# Verifying that classes on server and client are identical

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

In a Java RMI Client/Server application, is there a way to verify that the classes on the server and client are identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the codebase feature so that they are single-sourced from the codebase server.

Comment: The RMI codebase feature described in the RMI Specification and the Javadoc/Guide to Features/RMI.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you always have access to the bytes that make up the class (thru getResourceAsStream), and so if you really needed to, you can grab the bytes on the client and send them to the server, and compare.

Not sure why you need to go to this extent, normally all you care about is the serialization formats which is verified by the serialVersionUID value in the serializable class.